# how does clEnqueueMapBuffer work

Tags: opencl

Could anybody talk about the function `clEnqueueMapBuffer` work mechanism.  Actually I mainly concern what benefits on speed I can get from this function over `clEnqueueRead/WriteBuffer`.

**PS**:
Does `clEnqueueMapBuffer/clEnqueueMapImage` also alloc a buffer  from the CPU automatically?
If yes.
I want to manage my CPU buffer. I mean I malloc a big buffer first. Then if I need buffer. I can allocate it from the big buffer which I allocate first. How to make the `clEnqueueMapBuffer/clEnqueueMapImage` allocate buffer from the  big buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`clEnqueueMapBuffer`/`clEnqueueMapImage`

OpenCL mechanism for accessing memory objects instead of using `clEnqueueRead`/`Write`.   we can map a memory object on a device to a memory region on host. Once we have mapped the object we can read/write or modify anyway we like.

One more difference between `Read`/`Write` buffer and `clEnqueueMapBuffer` is the `map_flags` argument. If `map_flags` is set to `CL_MAP_READ`, the mapped memory will be read only, and if it is set as `CL_MAP_WRITE` the mapped memory will be write only, if you want both read + write then make the flag `CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE`.

Compared to read/write fns, memory mapping requires three step process>

1. Map the memory using `clEnqueueMapBuffer`.
2. transfer the memory from device to/from host via `memcpy`.
3. Unmap using `clEnqueueUnmapObject`.

It is common consensus that memory mapping gives significant improvement in performance compared to regular read/write, see here: [what's faster - AMD devgurus forum link](https://community.amd.com/message/1249219)

If you want to copy a image or rectangular region of image then you can make use of `clEnqueueMapImage` call as well.

References:

- [OpenCL in Action](http://www.manning.com/scarpino2/)
- [Heterogeneous computing with OpenCL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123877660)
- [Devgurus forum](http://devgurus.amd.com)

Comment: @ockuser : Does `clEnqueueMapBuffer/clEnqueueMapImage` also alloc a buffer  from the CPU automatically. If yes. I want to manage my CPU buffer. I mean I alloc a big buffer first. Then if I need buffer. I can alloc it from the big buffer which I alloc first. How to make the `clEnqueueMapBuffer/clEnqueueMapImage` alloc buffer from the  big buffer

Answer (score -1):

No, the map functions don't allocate memory. You'd do that in your call to clCreateBuffer.
If you allocate memory on the CPU and then try to use it, it will need to be copied to GPU accessible memory. To get memory accessible by both it's best to use CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR

```
clCreateBuffer(context, flags, size, host_ptr, &error);
```

context - Context for the device you're using.

flags - CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE

size - Size of the buffer in bytes, usually N * sizeof(data type)

host_ptr - Can be NULL or 0 meaning we have no existing data. You could add CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR to flags and pass in a pointer to the values you want copied to the buffer. This would save you having to copy via the mapped pointer. Beneficial if the values won't change.

Comment: If you _didn't_ use CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR in a buffer that you subsequently map then host memory _is_ allocated.